# Connecting a virtual machine and website on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure

I'm new to cloud hosting and Azure.
I want to create a Linux virtual machine on Azure to use it as a MongoDB server and then create an Azure Website that connects to that DB.
I've already found an [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-store-data-mongodb-vm/) that does almost exact same thing, but my question is (maybe it's stupid) - what if the DB is far-far away from my Website? How do I know that the time data travels from DB to Website is minimal?

Comment: What do you mean by "far-far away?" Are you deploying both to the same region? If you're not deploying the VM and Website to the same region, you will experience latency, along with bandwidth charges. The only way you'll know the timing is to measure it. And how you do that is a matter of opinion.

Comment: So if I have both the virtual machine and website on the same region basically I don't need to worry about the latency, right?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. There's *always* latency, but within a region, the latency is minimal. But, *acceptable* latency is something only you can answer (and again, you'd need to take your own measurements).

Comment: Got it, thanks. And one more question: in this scenario (VM DB<--> Website) what other people tend to worry about is that the DB (VM) is listening on public IP. Why do I need to worry about it except for security reasons?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a virtual network, then a subnet, then [connect the site and the VM to it](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/). Also in [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/) blog. No need to work with endpoints/ACL then.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments by [David Makogon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272109/david-makogon) if you want to use a separate virtual machine for your DB all you can and should do is just make sure that your Website and VM are on the same region. Then you can measure the latency and see if it's OK for you.

Some useful related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845966/connect-internally-to-a-virtual-machine-with-sql-server-from-web-sites-using-win), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065332/azure-websites-to-use-a-vm-running-sql-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943144/securing-a-network-between-a-website-and-vm-in-azure), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994147/is-azure-really-conveniant-for-a-medium-production-website-regarding-sql-azure-p).